# JavaScript: Adicionar objeto dentro uma array de objetos

Tags: javascript, google, operadores, objetos, google-charts

Eu tenho:

```
var options = {
    title: 'Titulo',
    width: largura,
    height: altura,
    vAxis: {
        title:"Porcentagem % em vendas",
        format: 'decimal'
    },
    hAxis: {
        title: "Seleção de clientes - Comutativa",
    }
}
```

Contudo depois de algum tempo, afim de gerar uma nova visualização, eu preciso passar para a variável *options* o seguinte valor:

```
vAxis:{
    ticks:[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
}
```

porém não sei o operador correto para dar um *push* em *options*, pois muitas vezes eu não sei o que tem dentro de *options* então preciso *somar(+=)* dentro do objeto *vAxis*

Comment: Não tenho certeza se entendi a dúvida, seria `options.vAxis.ticks = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]` ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, estou tão acostumado a usar push e += que as vezes esqueço de tentar o simples, mas não entendi, como ele pode atribuir um valor a variável que não existe? sua resposta está certa, ficaria feliz em marcar ela como correta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É isso que você procura?

```js
var largura = 15;
var altura = 25;
var options = {
    title: 'Titulo',
    width: largura,
    height: altura,
    vAxis: {
        title:"Porcentagem % em vendas",
        format: 'decimal'
    },
    hAxis: {
        title: "Seleção de clientes - Comutativa",
    }
}

console.log(options);

var nOptions = Object.assign({}, options, {
        vAxis: Object.assign({}, options.vAxis, { 
            ticks: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
        }) 
    });

console.log(nOptions);
```